# How to test a method which pass only its child object and expect the parent object to inherit the updated value of its child?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Hi I'm trying to create a test for a method which looks like this (**updateObject**):

MyService.class:

```
public Parent updateObject(Parent parent) {
    otherService.updateChild(parent.getChild());
    return parent;
}
```

OtherService.class:

```
public Child updateChild(Child child) {
    child.setName("updated name");
    return child;
}
```

I've tried to mock the updateChild method and return an object with the updated value.. but the parent object did not get its updated child.

My Failed Test:

```
public void testUpdateObject() {
   Parent parent = new Parent();
   Child currentChild = new Child();
   child.setName("current name");
   parent.setChild(currentChild);

   Child updatedChild = new Child();
   updatedChild.setName("updated name");

   when(otherService.updateChild(any(Child.class)).thenReturn(updatedChild);

   sut.updateObject(parent);

   assertEquals(updatedChild.getName(), parent.getChild().getName());
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: hmm I've tried to mock the updateChild method and return an object with the updated value.. but the parent object did not get its update.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt and explain what exactly go wrong?

Comment: I've added a sample test code to what I did.

Comment: what do you think `when(otherService.updateChild(any(Child.class)).thenReturn(updatedChild);` do? And why you think `currentChild` must change it state?

Comment: it mocks the method and return the object that I have inserted on the .thenReturn. I'm expecting that It will update the parent object.. I'm not quite that good on junit sir, hope you understand. Oh wait. should I pass the parent.getChild in the when(otherService.updateChild(..?

Comment: If you mock that call then actual `updateChild` method is not called, so `currentChild` will not change it state. You should either use real implementation of `otherService` instead of mock, or test what `updateObject` actually do. In later case you shold not check tahat state is changed, but only check that `updateChild` is invoked. Chose what option you want and I help you to achive result.

Answer (score 2):

- First, create a Parent object and a Child object and then set this
  child object into the parent object.
- Before calling the updateObject method, assert that the child
  object's name is null.
- Call the updateObject method and then assert that the name is set to
  "updated name".

So here is the test method for updateObject

```
@Test
public void testUpdateObject() {
  MyService myService = new MyService();

  Child child = new Child();

  Parent parent = new Parent();
  parent.setChild(child);

  asserNull(parent.getChild().getName());

  myService.updateObject(parent);

  assertEquals("updated name", parent.getChild().getName());
}
```

Comment: Only using `new MyService()` doesn't make clear how the dependency to `otherService` is initialized in the instance under test.